# heroku run rake db:seed is failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I made an web application on heroku and tried to add admin user by `heroku rake db:seed`. I can make users in an application, but I do not know how to code well in seeds.rb. 
`heroku run rake db:migrate` was successful.
As of now, I am not able to log in with `admin` and `adminpw`.

**timestamp_create_user.rb**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :userid
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**seeds.rb**

```
User.create!(
   userid: 'admin',
   email: 'admin@testing.com',
   password: 'adminpw',
   passwor_confirmation: 'adminpw',
   admin: true
)
```

**heroku logs**

> > , [2019-02-27T02:46:45.074640 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC

Comment: There could be a few different issues. Check your `password_confirmation` spelling...are you using Devise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can diagnose errors by doing the following. Run `rails c`

Now add the following line in prompt of `rails c`

```
u = User.create!(
   userid: 'admin',
   email: 'admin@testing.com',
   password: 'adminpw',
   passwor_confirmation: 'adminpw',
   admin: true
)
```

Now write the following to see what is the error or is it valid?

```
u.valid?
```

If you get false, that means you have errors in your information or validation is not being fullfiled. To know exactly what is issue use following command

```
u.errors.messages
```

Now you will knwo what is error and you can modify it to get proper seeding of data.